# How to pass data from a webpage loaded into a div to the page that loaded it

Tags: javascript, html, interaction

I have two web applications. I loaded project 1 into project 2 via a div. Now I want to pass data from project 1 to project 2. But I don't know how to go about it. Can anybody help me out?

Here is the code:

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    (function () {
      var externalEl = document.createElement('div'); // is a node
      externalEl.innerHTML = '<div><object type="text/html" data="http://localhost:3333/payment/P2ZpcnN0TmFtZT1UaW1vdGh5Jmxhc3ROYW1lPVVpamlhdGFsb3ImcGhvbmU9MDgxNjk1MjI3OTAmZW1haWw9dGltb3RoeXVpamlhdGFsb3JAeWFob28uY29tJmNvdW50cnk9TmlnZXJpYSZhbW91bnQ9NTAmY3VycmVuY3k9TkdOJmRpdkNvZGU9MDEmaXRlbUNvZGU9MzAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwJnJlZGlyVXJsPWh0dHA6Ly8xMjcuMC4wLjEvcG9zdC9ndzIucGhwJnBheW1lbnRUaXRsZT1TdGFuYmljJmxvZ29QYXRoPWh0dHBzOi8vcmNjZ2V0b3VyLm9yZy9pc3JhZWwyMDIwL3RlbXBsYXRlL2Fzc2V0cy9pbWcvbG9nby5wbmcmbWVyY2hhbnRSZWY9R0YxMjMmdHlwZT1jYXJkJnNob3dNb2RhbD0x" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue"></object></div>';

      document.body.appendChild(externalEl);

      // I want to know whether user clicked on male or female from the page I loaded into the above div
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the how project 1 was loaded into project 2:

[image]

Comment: You could try <iframe> may be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the end product is going to be slightly more complex than a simple male/female selection (otherwise I'd suggest just processing it within project 2, rather than nesting project 1 as an iFrame). Without knowing the specifics of how you want the nested part to interact; I can only give a broad example.

In project 1 you'll want to add something along these lines in the relevant Javascript block:

```
window.parent.postMessage({ message: "getAppData", value: MyDataToPass }, "*");
```

Because an iframe is essentially just a new browser session nested within a page - this passes a message to the outer page containing the data you specify.

In project 2, you'd want to substitute what you've got in your question with something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>IFrame Example</title>
  </head>
<body>
<iframe src="inputForm.html" >
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

You'd need to point the src at the relevant URL in project 1.

Then within the javascript for the page, you'll to create an event listener.

```
window.addEventListener("message", this.receiveMessage, false);
```

With a corresponding function to process the data.

```
 receiveMessage = (event: any) => {
    const message = event.data.message;

    switch (message) {
      case 'getAppData':
        Process the data here
        break;
    }
    ...
  }
```